# Add drupal to exsisting Angular project

Tags: angularjs, drupal

I got a angular project and I want to add drupal to it. 
I want the admin to be able to add new content in drupal which will show in a feed on my page.

Is this possible? 
Been trying to find a guide but it seems like I'm out of luck.

Comment: you can start with drupal as a backend and services module for supplying your angular project with feeds

Comment: any suggestions on where to start looking?

Comment: Download and install drupal from https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal and then follow the installation directions from https://www.drupal.org/documentation/install/beginners and then install services module by following the https://www.drupal.org/documentation/install/modules-themes/modules-7

Comment: Ok, that part I've covered. But Im more wondering about the next step. How to do the feed part as you called it. Setting upp drupal is no problem, its accassing the content from it thats my goal.

Comment: follow https://www.drupal.org/node/2424977 and install libraries module, enable REST Server module, in admin/structure/services add new service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using drupal 7 you can download drupal 8 which is in beta and provides a restful api service "out of the box".

Answer (score 1):

If you have the services module installed you can find all available REST calls under the services tab.

If you want for example fetching nodes you can fire a request to `www.your-backend.org/api/node/`.
Or consume data for a view with `www.your-backend.org/api/views/view-name`

To Integrate this in you Angular forntend you can use [**ng-drupal-7-services**](https://github.com/BioPhoton/ng-drupal-7-services).

This Module provides nearly all possible API calls to drupal as well as a module to easily handle authentication to you backend.
It sets:

- session data
- cookie data
- X-CSRF Token

At drupanionic.org you will fin demos for plain angular and ionic.